# How to insert,update data row when database is read only?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, t-sql

I have a database in `sql server` that working with `WPF` application. Thousands of data inserting db in per a second by users.

My client wants to update database as a read only. But I have some apprehensions about that.

If I update database as a read-only, is it block inserting or updating data from application?

Comment: doesn't read-only means "read-only" ?

Comment: You can't write - `READ_ONLY` means that users can read data from the database but not modify it.

Comment: As @PrabhatG states - then read-only is for read-only purpose and you not allowed to write to your objects.

Comment: It's obvious you can't have a readonly database and inserting rows in the same time. Maybe  your client wants to have all the other tables defined as readonly. Otherwise, maybe your client refers to user's permissions.

Comment: My ideas same too that read only database is not able to insert or update data. Unfortunately my firms customer wants it read only. Sucks situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting database to read-only means that users can read data from the database but not modify it.

What you can do if you need to have `read only` database but at the same time need to modify the data is to divide your tables in different files groups.

It's really complicated solution but having different files groups can allow to have `read-only` tables and tables which can be modified. Also, for read-only files groups a compression can be apply that can reduce the size of the whole group.

More information about the set up and the requirements of having `read-only` files group can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190257%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/17/sql-server-marking-filegroup-as-readonly-with-sql-server/).

Answer (score 3):

Read only means **Read Only**. When a database is in read-only mode you can only read data from it, and not make any changes.

To answer your question, to insert or update data into a read-only database, you need to put it into [read-write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options#arguments) mode first:

```
ALTER DATABASE [TESTDB] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

While it's not unusual to want a database in read-only mode, it defeats the point entirely if you're regularly making changes. [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96209/implications-of-setting-read-write) on dba.stackexchange has some answers if you're just looking to make small changes during defined maintenance windows.

Comment: Please avoid answering for sake of answering. 1 liners are appreciated as comment. Else backup your answer properly with Microsoft links stating why, what, ifs and buts.

Answer (score 0):

impossible, read-only means read-only: no inputs, no updates.

However, you can copy the contents of the table and update in this at-the-side temp table and try seamlessly integrate into your main table at regular intervals (when io-load on your main table is low or at service down-times...)